# how to use more than one validation in one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, validationsummary

I have 2 radio button (radiobtn1 and radiobtn2) in one group and 4 text box which names are a, b, c, d. And end of the page there is standard button. I add asp:requiredFieldValidators to all of textboxes. So when I clicked my button asp:validationsummary works for all of textboxes.

I want to do that if radiobtn1 was clicked, validationsummary should work for textbox a and b, if radiobtn2 was clicked, validationsummary should work for should textbox c and d.

how can I do that?

thx.

Comment: Use a `CustomValidator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working as of your requirement..

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="group 1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="group 1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="group 2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="group 2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  Text="valid first 2" CausesValidation="True" GroupName="g" ValidationGroup="group 1"/>
&nbsp;   &nbsp;  <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Text="valid last 2" CausesValidation="True" GroupName="g" ValidationGroup="group 2" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: yeah. It is true. I find it already but now I have another problem. Can you also help me at that topic ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130096/validate-function-doesnt-fire